# Android: How to pass parameters from OnClickListener to another

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I'm new to android and Java. I wanna pass a variable (ac) from OnClickListener to another. I've tried this way, but i receive this error: cannot resolve symbol 'ac'. Can you help me please?

```
Button Calculate = (Button) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.button);
Button buttonb = (Button) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.buttonb);
final TextView tvac = (TextView) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.tvac);
final TextView tvh = (TextView) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.tvh);
final EditText eta = (EditText) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.eta);
final EditText etn = (EditText) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.etn);
final EditText etb = (EditText) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.etb);

Calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Double a = new Double(eta.getText().toString());
        Double n = new Double(etn.getText().toString());
        Double ac = a*n;
        tvac.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.tvresultados2) + " " + ac);
    }
});
buttonb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        double b = new Double(etb.getText().toString());
        double h = ac/b;          //error: cannot resolve symbol 'ac'
        tvh.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvh.setText("h = " + h);
    }
});
```

Comment: This appears to be a scoping issue.  Try moving `ac` declaration up above the `onClickListener`.

Comment: I've tried this option, but to do that i need to declare 'ac' as a final.

Comment: Then move `ac` up to a field (global) variable.

Comment: it is a java's basics please read some toturial fx: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most simple way is to declare global variable. Declare your `ac` outside of onCreate scope instead of inside of it.

```
public Double ac; // global variable

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

Button Calculate = (Button) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.button);
Button buttonb = (Button) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.buttonb);
final TextView tvac = (TextView) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.tvac);
final TextView tvh = (TextView) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.tvh);
final EditText eta = (EditText) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.eta);
final EditText etn = (EditText) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.etn);
final EditText etb = (EditText) theLayout.findViewById(R.id.etb);

Calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Double a = new Double(eta.getText().toString());
        Double n = new Double(etn.getText().toString());
        ac = a*n;
        tvac.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.tvresultados2) + " " + ac);
    }
});
buttonb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        double b = new Double(etb.getText().toString());
        double h = ac;          //assign global variable into h
        tvh.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvh.setText("h = " + h);
    }
});

}
```